# Fallback route for routes that do not exist

Tags: php, error-handling, url-routing, silex

I have a project in Silex, with the standard defined routes, but for routes that do not exist, I would like to reroute or forward to the homepage, or an error page.

I'm not seeing this in the documentation, but I don't see why this isn't possible.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Copying the [error handler](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-Skeleton/blob/master/src/controllers.php) from [Silex Skeleton](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-Skeleton), you can do it easily:

```
<?php

$app->error(function (\Exception $e, Request $request, $code) use ($app) {
    if ($app['debug']) {
        return;
    }

    // 404.html, or 40x.html, or 4xx.html, or error.html
    $templates = array(
            'errors/'.$code.'.html',
            'errors/'.substr($code, 0, 2).'x.html',
            'errors/'.substr($code, 0, 1).'xx.html',
            'errors/default.html',
    );

    return new Response($app['twig']->resolveTemplate($templates)->render(array('code' => $code)), $code);
});
```

Or you may want to redirect / forward (the former does a round trip to the browser whereas the latter does not). Check the docs for the [redirect / forward](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#redirects), basically instead of returning a response based on a rendered template you just need to `return $app->redirect` or `return $app->forward`

Answer (score 0):

Symfony2 has section about customizing error pages in Cookbook.
Look at [How to Customize Error Pages](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html)